# changing image source dynamically via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am designing a chat application. In that i am using functionality that if someone clicks on the chap display picture , a side panel opens up with contact information and corresponding image of the person whose chat it is. So what i want is to dynamically assign the src of display picture to src of image in the side panel on click .
Here is my code snippet.

```
$(".chat-top").click(function(){
      var ig= document.getElementById("contacti");
      var ig2=document.getElementById("imgr");
      ig2.src=ig.src;
  });
```

chat-top is the div on click of which side panel comes.
contacti is the id of display image tag and imgr is the id of side panel image tag.

any suggestions..?

Comment: You didn't state your problem

Comment: share html also

Comment: what's your question? Is there a problem with your code? Presumably there is otherwise you wouldn't ask your question, but you didn't tell us what the problem is. You stated your requirements, but didn't say which part of them isn't fulfilled. on the face of it, there's nothing _obviously_ wrong with the code. Perhaps your element IDs are wrong, or perhaps your event doesn't fire. You can show us the HTML to help with the first question, and do some debugging yourself to help with the second.

Comment: my problem is that the given code is not working according to the way in wihich  desried output is. for ex: if i clicked on some img.jpg then then side panel image src should be img.jpg .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your image's `src` attributes by using the JQuery `attr()` function like following:

```js
$(".chat-top").click(function () {
  console.log("before:", $("#contacti").attr("src"), $("#imgr").attr("src"));

  var igSrc= $("#contacti").attr("src");
  $("#imgr").attr("src", igSrc);
      
  console.log("after:", $("#contacti").attr("src"), $("#imgr").attr("src"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="chat-top"> change </button>
<img id="contacti" src="example"/>
<img id="imgr" src="secondExample"/>
```

Comment: thanks alot. its working fine now.

Comment: Please mark it as answered.